# Dependency problem when installing Kernel 4.2.6 on NUC computer running Trusty

Tags: kernel, dependencies, iwlwifi

I installed Linux kernel 4.2.6 to get wifi working on a 3165 device on a NUC5 computer running Trusty new install. This stable 4.2.6 kernel actually has wily in the package names. It gave a dependency problem:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.2.6-040206-generic:
 linux-headers-4.2.6-040206-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.11).
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.2.6-040206-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

libc6 is v2.19 so I don't understand why there is a problem let alone how to fix it.
PS I do not yet have the 'score' to make comments so please let me know how to reply to any questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me: I downloaded the i386 packages rather than the amd64 packages. I 'removed' the i386 packages and installed the amd64 packages and now OK.

Comment: Jessica, don't download stuff like that silly (: use `apt-get` to do the installation and it will download it for you. First, run `sudo apt-get update` before you begin searching. Then, to see what version is available through `apt-get`, you can search like so: `apt-cache search libc6 | grep libc6` and when you see the package you want, you can get more info on that package like so: `apt-cache show libc6` or, `apt-cache show libc6 | grep Version:` If everything looks good, run: `sudo apt-get install libc6`